# Minifier with GAE + Angular JS

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-closure-compiler, angularjs

Can you explain, or point to good resource on how to setup a minifier (preferably google closure) to work with Google App Engine.

I use AngularJS for client side. So have bunch of JS files, and like to serve it as one, minified during production. Without manually editing index.html for which files to server, and not having trouble with GAE setup, how can I achieve this?

thanks.

Comment: why not do it in post deploy script instead?

Comment: @Shay, I am in development of my first GAE app. Not sure all the options available. If you can brief a bit about the approach as answer, that would be great.

Comment: Are you familiair with yeoman: http://briantford.com/blog/angular-yeoman.html

Comment: Basically it got nothing todo with GAE directly, you use a deploy script that will upload the app but before it deploy it scans the app folder and run the minifer tool of your choice on any js file.

Comment: if you want to load some of the template via Jinja you could use Webassets with an angular bundle look at the YAMLLoader for webassets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) has an ant build script that searches your html files for js and css, minifies and concatenates etc, etc creating a published version of your code. You will probably want to tweak it to ensure that things like jquery and angularjs get put in the right place. I hadn't used ant for awhile and it was pretty comprehensible. I imagine you could replace whatever js minifier is there with something like closure.

Just as an aside, make sure that you use $inject [dependency injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) so the minifier doesn't mess up your angular code.

hope this helps

--dan

Answer (score 1):

You can let App Engine do the optimization work for you, thanks to the Page Speed service, which you can enable from the admin console settings page:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#pagespeed